# Action of exponential of multiplication operator on $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let $X: L^2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be a multiplication operator, i.e. $f(x) \mapsto xf(x)$ for $f \in L^2$. Multiplication operators are known to be self-adjoint on some dense subset of $L^2$, and so by Stone's theorem on one-parameter unitary groups $X$ is the infinitesimal generator of some one-parameter group of operators $U(t)$ such that $U(t) = e^{itX}$.

I am interested in explicitly finding the action of $e^{itX}$ on an $L^2$ function $f$. In an analogy with the heat semigroup, I think this can be determined by thinking of $e^{itX}$ as the solution to the differential equation
$$\partial_t f = ixf$$
but I don't think this would make sense since $f$ is only assumed to be a function of $x$.

How can one find and/or describe how $e^{itX}$ acts on $L^2$ functions? Can anything be said about $e^{tx}$?

Comment: My answer below applies for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, which I assume was your intention. If you really wanted $\mathbb{R}^n$, then you’ll have to correct your definition of $X$ (it only works in one dimension).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the differential equation angle gives you. Maybe someone else can answer that. But the action is very easy to describe.

If $X$ is the map $f(x) \mapsto xf(x)$, then $U(t)$ is the map $f(x) \mapsto e^{itx}f(x)$. It’s still an action by pointwise multiplication, but now it’s a one-parameter ($t$) family of unitary operators on $L^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are correct, I should have written $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I have correct my post. I think I messed up the setup of the differential equation but I think your answer agrees with what I had in mind. How did you deduce that the action is multiplication by $e^{itx}$?

Comment: That's a consequence of the [functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Functional_calculus), which comes from the spectral theorem.  Basically, your operator $X$ has already been "diagonalized" (it's a multiplication operator), so the functional calculus for $X$ applied to any bounded Borel-measurable $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ will just yield the pointwise multiplication operator $f(x) \mapsto g(x)f(x)$ on $L^2$.  That takes care of $g(x) = e^{itx}.$  Your $g(x) = e^{tx}$ should follow the same pattern, but it would yield an unbounded operator again.

Comment: I like Reed and Simon's Methods of Mathematical Physics 1 for the various statements of the spectral theorem/functional calculus, but they don't cover the case where $g$ (the function you want to apply to $X$) is unbounded.  I assume there are some domain subtleties there, given that both $X$ and $g(x)=e^{tx}$ are unbounded, so I'd use $e^{tX}$ with caution.  They do cover Stone's theorem, though!

Comment: Thank you! I have gone through Reed and Simon's book in the past but I never fully understood this point. If we use the functional calculus and diagonalize $X$ so that $e^{itX}$ acts by multiplication of $e^{it\lambda}$ in the eigenspace spanned by each $\lambda$ in the spectrum of $X$, how do we conclude that $e^{itX}$ acts by multiplication of $e^{itx}$ in the original basis we started with (i.e. before diagonalizing)?

Comment: You can think of acting “diagonally” and “by pointwise multiplication” as being synonymous in this context. It’s not always true for a generic self-adjoint $\tilde{X}: L^2 \rightarrow L^2$ that $e^{it\tilde{X}}$ is just pointwise multiplication - you may have to change bases first. But *your* $X$ is already acting diagonally by definition - no basis change required. So its functional calculus is straightforward.

Comment: Oh I see! So because $X$ is already acting as a multiplication operator $L^2$ is already in a diagonalized basis, so $e^{itx}$ is also just multiplication. I suppose for general self-adjoint $X$ then one would have to use the differential operator $(\partial_t - X)$ to figure out the action of its exponential. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: You're welcome!  Again, I'm not sure about the differential stuff.  Hopefully someone can comment on that.  But it's definitely true that your $X$ operator $f(x) \mapsto xf(x)$ has the obvious functional calculus.  It's exactly the type of operator that the spectral theorem aims for.  (That might be more obvious if you write $f(\lambda) \mapsto \lambda f(\lambda)$.)